# creating custom options in unix

Tags: c, unix, getopt

I want to created new options in cat using c file

I am new to Unix so I don`t know what to use.

I want to compile

```
./mycat -s 16 foo
```

16 is size of buffer and foo is file name

using mycat.c file and code is below

```
#include <stdio.h> /* fprintf */
#include <unistd.h> /* getopt */
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit */

/* debug mode (-d option) */
int is_debug = 0;

/* prints log message to stderr only when -d is available */
#define LOG(fmt, ...) do { if (is_debug) fprintf(stderr, fmt "\n", __VA_ARGS__); } while (0)


/* Non-portable functions for checking stdio's buffer size, etc. */

/* checks if the given stream is line-buffered */
int is_stdio_linebuffered(FILE *stream) {
    return (stream->_flags & __SLBF) > 0;
}

/* checks if the given stream is NOT buffered */
int is_stdio_unbuffered(FILE *stream) {
    return (stream->_flags & __SNBF) > 0;
}

/* obtains the buffer size of the given stream */
int stdio_buffer_size(FILE *stream) {
return stream->_bf._size;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int opt, i;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "dm:")) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {
    case 'd':
        is_debug = 1;
        break;
    case 'm':
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: message is '%s'\n", argv[0], optarg);
        break;
    case 'i': ???????????????????????????????????
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-d] [-m message] args...\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

  for (i = optind; i < argc; i++) {
      LOG("[%d] %s", i, argv[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

so c file need to add some code

but I don`t know what function to use

how to make -i option which gets buffer size and file name?

Comment: Perhaps start by reading the documentation to `getopt()`? To do so run `man getopt`.

Comment: the functions that are checking if the output is buffered or not are performing EXACTLY the same thing with the same results  Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `getopt()` is

```
int getopt(int argc, char * const argv[], const char *optstring);
```

In `optstring`, the option characters must be specified. An option character is followed by a single `:` only if it always needs an argument. Two semicolons are used for optional argument and no semicolon for those always without arguments.

You need an option `-s` which takes an integer argument.

In your usage of `getopt()`, there are two other options `d` and `m` which don't take argument (I assumed that `m` doesn't take an argument as you wanted `./mycat -s 16 foo` to compile. Change it to take optional argument if you like).

So `getopt()` should be

```
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "dms:")) != -1) {
    ....
    ....
}
```

And in `case 's':` of the `switch` statement

```
case 's': 
iopt = strtol(optarg, &dp, 10); 
if(iopt==0 && errno == ERANGE)
{
    errno = 0;
    perror("Number out of range");
}
else if(*dp != 0)
{
    printf("\nNot a numeric value. Non number part found");
}
break;
```

`optarg` would point to the beginning of a string which is the argument of the `s` option.

Since we need it as a number, you need to convert the string to number.

`strtol()` is used for this. It returns the number of type `long` if successful.
If the number is too big to contained in `long`, it returns `0` and sets `errno` to `ERANGE`. To check these error codes, you must include `errno.h`.

You could use other functions in the same family as `strtol()` to get values of other types. eg: `strtoll()` for `long long`.